# Loop nested loops

Tags: c#, loops, nested

I would like to create a nested loop where the nesting depth determined by the size on an array. For example I have an array of integers [image] and I would like to check all tuples [image] where [image: Text]. Is there a way to do this simply in c# (or any other language)?

The only easy idea I had was to just multiply the numbers and do a for loop up to that number but unfortunately the product reaches the int limit. Also in this case I have no way to add extra conditions on each level.

Here's a small example and the product approach:

```
int[] a = new int[]{2, 3, 2};  //we have an array like this. In the description above it is a_1, a_2, a_3
void f(int[] i) //I have a function that works on an array input
{...}
bool check(int[] i) //I have a checker function, with an array parameter too
{...}
//And I would like to perform this function on all these arrays
//f({0, 0, 0})
//f({0, 0, 1})
//010
//011
//020
//021
//100
//101
//110
//111
//120
//f({1, 2, 1})
//But if let's say check({1, 0}) is false then don't perform the f function on {1, 0, 0} and {1, 0, 1}
//A simple implementation if we know the size of the array a is the following
for(int i1=0;i1<a[0];i1++)
{
    if(!check({i1}))
        continue;
    for(int i2=0;i2<a[1];i2++)
    {
        if(!check({i1, i2}))
            continue;
        for(int i3=0;i3<a[2];i3++)
        {
            if(!check({i1, i2, i3}))
                continue;
            f({i1, i2, i3});
        }
    }
}
//But this obviously fails as we have no idea apriori of the size of the array a
//An alternative I have is the following:
int prod = 1;
foreach(int x in a)
{
    prod *= x;
}
for(int c=0;c<prod;c++)
{
    int d=c;
    int[] i = new int[a.Length];
    for(int l=0;l<a.Length;l++)
    {
        i[l]=d%(a[l]);
        d /= a[l];
    }
    f(i);
}
//But the problem with this implementation is that in my case prod is larger than the int limit. Also this loops through all the incorrect cases too, where the check function can highly reduce the number of cases to calculate.
```

Comment: `Is there a way to do this simply in c#` sure there is, what have you tried, what isn't working and expected output? Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've edited the question with an example and a clearer explanation I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. The idea is that increasing the i value by one is really easy and we can check the condition that we don't overstep the a values and don't violate the check function easily. Below is a code that works

```
        int[] a = ...;
        void f(int[] i){...}
        bool check(int[] i){...}
        int n = a.Length;
        int[] i = new int[n];
        while (true) //keep increasing the coordinates of i, while we can
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                {
                    int[] il = copyFirst(i, l);

                    while(!check(il)) //check for all first few coordinates if it is correct, skip if incorrect. 
        //There is a way to improve this even further, as we don't have to check the first few
        // coords if it was correct before, so should only care about the recently changed section
                    {
                        i = increase(a, i, l);
                        if (i == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            il = copyFirst(i, l);
                        }
                    }
                }
                f(i);
                i = increase(a, i, n-1);
                if (i == null) return;
            }

            int[] copyFirst(int[] i, int l) //this is just a small helper function to copy the first few elements of i, to use in the check
            {
                int[] ret = new int[l];
                for (int k = 0; k < l; k++)
                {
                    ret[k] = i[k];
                }
                return ret;
            }

            int[] increase(int[] a, int[] i, int l) //this results in the increased vector and in null if we've reached the end
            {
                for (int k = l; k >= 0; k--)
                {
                    i[k] = i[k] + 1;
                    if (i[k] >= a[k])
                    {
                        i[k] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
```